# How to efficiently remove rows that match criteria on another sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a requirement to remove a list of exceptions/exclusions from a large (115244 rows) data set.
The total number of exclusions is 1133.

I have the following piece of code:

```
function removeExclusions() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  
  const exclusionSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Exclusion List");
  const excludedAccounts = exclusionSheet
    .getRange("C2:C" + exclusionSheet.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .reduce(
      (o, [c]) =>
        Object.assign(o, {
          [c]: true
        }),
      {}
    );
  Logger.log("Total accounts to remove: " + excludedAccounts); 
  
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Sheet");
  const dataSheetMatches = dataSheet
    .getRange("A2:A" + dataSheet.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
      if (excludedAccounts[a]) ar.push(i + 2);
      return ar;
    }, [])
    .reverse();
  Logger.log("Accounts left to remove: " + dataSheetMatches.length); 
  
  dataSheetMatches.forEach((r) => {
    dataSheet.deleteRow(r);
    Logger.log("Row:" + r + " has been deleted");
  });
}
```

However, due to the size of the dataset/number of accounts/rows, this needs to run against - it takes an eternity and hits the timeout that Google has on Apps Script runtimes.

I need a much more efficient way to do the following:
Check the "Exclusion List" sheet (column C), then remove the row in the "Data Sheet" when it matches against column A.

Rows A-O can be cleared. Columns P-S header row (1) contains some formulas that I need to keep.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
So I have amended my code to the following:

```
function removeExclusions() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const exclusionSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Exclusion List");
  const exclusionRange = exclusionSheet.getRange("C2:C");
  const exclusionVals = exclusionRange.getDisplayValues();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Sheet");
  const dataSheetRange = dataSheet.getRange("A2:O");
  let dataSheetVals = dataSheetRange.getValues();
  dataSheetVals = dataSheetVals.filter((data) => {
    return !exclusionVals.includes(data[0]);
  });
  Logger.log(dataSheetVals);
}
```

However, it's still showing the rows I would expect it to exclude...

Comment: `.map()` and `.filter` are both faster than `.reduce()`. The first `.reduce()` should be a `.map()` and it seems like `.filter()` is a better fit for the second `.reduce()`.

Comment: Ranges like A2:A return null between lastRow() and maxxRows() thus requiring filtering use getRange(2,1.sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); instead.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I have taken some advice and decided to use a filter instead, however, it's still not returning the results I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it takes an eternity and hits the timeout that Google has on Apps
> Script runtimes.

The cause of this is

```
dataSheet.deleteRow(r);
```

Even if you try it on 20 rows sheet, it's slow, you can almost observe rows being deleted one by one.

Besides that, 100K+ rows is sometimes too much for Google Sheets, the response time is slower.

### The strategy you could use

1. Pull all data from "Data Sheet" into variable, using getValues(). (exclude formula columns if possible)
2. Pull "Exclusion List" column C into variable just like you did in the code
3. Use .filter on "Data Sheet" values array to create new array by removing the unwanted rows
4. Clear "Data Sheet" values (exclude formula columns if possible)
5. Write reduced data into "Data Sheet", using setValues().

### Notes

1. This approach can take a long time too. It's much faster than deleteRow, but getValues and setValues on 100K+ rows and I guess 15-20 columns will take some time. The rough estimation of the execution time would be to do manual select all/copy/paste tests on the "Data Sheet" and see how long you have to wait.
2. If some person/process is adding/removing/moving/editing "Data Sheet" at the same time your function runs, you may have data loses. If you can prevent this by using some overnight once per day trigger to run your code you should be fine.
3. In general your code can break, you could make a duplicate of the sheet (to serve as a backup) at the beginning and then if everything is executed without an error delete the duplicate sheet at the end.
4. In general you should consider moving your data from Google Sheets to some platform that can handle larger amounts of records, I use BigQuery for such scenarios.

***Edit: response to your amended code***

Assuming that values you are comparing are strings:

```
function somethingLikeThis() {

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    // Load "Exclusion List" column C to array of strings
    const exclusionSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Exclusion List");
    const lastRowExclusionSheet = exclusionSheet.getLastRow();
    const exlusionList = exclusionSheet
        .getRange(2, 3, lastRowExclusionSheet - 2 + 1) // Data starts at row 2, column is C
        .getValues()
        .map(row => row[0].toString()) // Convert array of arrays to array of strings
        .filter(el => el.length > 0); // Remove empty rows if any

    // Read values from "Data Sheet"
    const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Sheet");
    const lastRowDataSheet = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    const oldDataRange = dataSheet
        .getRange(2, 1, lastRowDataSheet - 2 + 1, 15) // Data starts at row 2, columns A-O
    const oldDataValues = oldDataRange.getValues();

    // Clear "Data Sheet"
    oldDataRange.clearContent();

    // Keep rows where column A value is not on the "Exclusion List"
    const newDataValues = oldDataValues
        .filter(row => exlusionList.indexOf(row[0].toString()) < 0);

    // Write reduced rows to "Data Sheet"
    if (newDataValues.length > 0) {
        dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, newDataValues.length, newDataValues[0].length)
            .setValues(newDataValues);
    }

}
```

Code is not tested, I don't have actual sheets. Try using getLastRow(), ranges like "C2:C" can pick empty rows at the end of the sheet.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, tested and more or less works fine. For some reason, it's not removing a small handful of results - but it was about 6 users or something.